# Wifi issue. Dell Latitude E6400 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

Fresh install of 12.04 on a Dell LAtitude E6400 and came up with the wireless issues. I'm fairly new to linux command line, but have been using ubuntu for several years now on a dell D630 so I researched, sudo'd, reinstalled and now the light turns on and off with the external switch and Im able to enable the wireless option in the connectivity settings but it still wont see any wifi networks.

Anyhow I obviously need help to get it to connected.

Here's the results from the following commands:

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated   Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 03)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 21)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 11)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:b9:c1:6a:60  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:99 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31276 (31.2 KB)  TX bytes:18964 (18.9 KB)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6ae0000-f6b00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4684 (4.6 KB)  TX bytes:4684 (4.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:e4:00:12:08:39  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**lshw -C network**

```
  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:26:b9:c1:6a:60
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.1.4-k firmware=1.7-7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 memory:f6ae0000-f6afffff memory:f6adb000-f6adbfff ioport:efe0(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 78:e4:00:12:08:39
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=508.1084 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

**nm-tool**

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            b43
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        78:E4:00:12:08:39

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:26:B9:C1:6A:60

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Laptop connects no problems through the wire, if you look at nm-tools it says the wireless is disconnected. So how do I get it to say connected?

Answer (score 2):

I like to use WICD because it is a simple and easy to use network manager.
Its a very good alternative to network manager in Ubuntu and it seems to
always work when Network Manager doesn't.
To install it just open up the terminal.
Now download the latest NetworkManager, in case you need to reinstall it
if WICD doesn't work

```
    sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome 

Then to install it

    sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk 

And now you need to uninstall NetworkManager:

    sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Now you can find WICD in your menu
Start WICD, find the network you want to use and enter the information needed, password, encryption, etcetera and choose Automatically Connect to this network.
You should be good to go!

WICD may also be available in Ubuntu Update Manager so you can look there first
but it is important to uninstall Network Manager completely to prevent conflicts!!

Comment: Thanking you! WICD worked a treat. Never thought of using a different network manager and now I feel stupid, but I can live with that. Thanks for the help and the quick reply.